# I can copy data from one workbook to another, but I need it to be smarter and replace existing data

Tags: vba, excel

Allow me to currently explain what I currently have and what it does.

I have one large excel sheet that contains thousands of lines of data from Facebook exports. Basically, every week, we are given about 30 different sheets which contain data from Facebook pages (what was posted, how many likes it got, etc). This all needs to go into one giant database of data. So I use a VBA code to automatically copy the data that I need and paste it in the right place.

If I'm honest, it's been Frankensteined from various other codes I have found. But it works.

```
Sub CopyFacebook_v2()
Dim shtOrigin As Worksheet
Dim strFile As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set shtReach = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")

strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename

If CStr(strFile) <> "False" Then

Country = InputBox("What MARKET is this data from?")
Page = InputBox("What is the name of the PAGE?")

shtReach.Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Country
shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "Facebook"
shtReach.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Page

Set shtOrigin = Workbooks.Open(strFile).Sheets(2)
Set shtL = shtOrigin.Range("L1")
Set shtK = shtOrigin.Range("K1")
Set shtJ = shtOrigin.Range("J1")

'**Version 3

    'ID
    shtOrigin.Range("B2:B5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, -13)
    'URL
    shtOrigin.Range("C2:C5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 41)
    'Message
    shtOrigin.Range("D2:D5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, -11)
    'Type
    shtOrigin.Range("E2:E5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, -7)
    'Date
    shtOrigin.Range("H2:H5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)
    'Comment
        If shtL = "comment" Then
            shtOrigin.Range("L2:L5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 8)
        End If
        If shtK = "comment" Then
            shtOrigin.Range("K2:K5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 8)
        End If
        If shtJ = "comment" Then
            shtOrigin.Range("J2:J5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 8)
        End If
    'Like
    If shtL = "like" Then
            shtOrigin.Range("L2:L5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 9)
        End If
        If shtK = "like" Then
            shtOrigin.Range("K2:K5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 9)
        End If
        If shtJ = "like" Then
            shtOrigin.Range("J2:J5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 9)
        End If
    'Share
    If shtL = "share" Then
            shtOrigin.Range("L2:L5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 11)
        End If
        If shtK = "share" Then
            shtOrigin.Range("K2:K5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 11)
        End If
        If shtJ = "share" Then
            shtOrigin.Range("J2:J5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 11)
        End If


Set shtOrigin = Workbooks.Open(strFile).Sheets(1)

    'Organic Reach
    shtOrigin.Range("J3:J5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4)
    'Paid Reach
    shtOrigin.Range("K3:K5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 7)
    'Total Organic Views
    shtOrigin.Range("Y3:Y5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 15)
    'Total Paid Views
    shtOrigin.Range("AA3:AA5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 16)
    '3% Organic Views
    shtOrigin.Range("AC3:AC5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 17)
    '3% Paid Views
    shtOrigin.Range("AE3:AE5000").Copy Destination:=shtReach.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 18)


   Application.CutCopyMode = False

   ActiveWorkbook.Close False

    Set shtOrigin = Nothing
    Set shtL = Nothing
    Set shtK = Nothing
    Set shtJ = Nothing

Set shtDestin = Nothing

Columns("G").Replace What:="SharedVideo", _
                        Replacement:="Video", _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False

Run "FillColBlanks_Offset"

Else

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "No valid file selected", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Copy Error"

Set shtDestin = Nothing

End If

End Sub
```

So, while this currently works, it's also a fairly blunt hammer. For example, because the data often overlaps with existing data, we have to go through and delete any duplicates. It also copies massive bulks of text, instead of line by line, making it difficult to do much.

What I'm looking for is a way for the code to double check whether the URL (column B) exists already. If it does, I'd like to override the numbers over the top of the existing data.

If the URL doesn't already exist, I would like to create a new line for the data.

I've tried researching a solution, but nothing seems to fit this case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What have you researched? I'd have thought you could use FInd or Match to see if something already exists

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the column and use find, if it finds the value, it will use that found row as the destination row. The loop may take a while.
If it does not find it, it will find the last row and use that row as the destination row.
The code loops through column N in the Sheets(2) and finds the value in Column B sheets("Data")

Please note, this is an example, and you will have to edit the code to suite.

```
Sub DiT()
    Dim LstRw As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim c As Range, FnD As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Long

    Set sh = Sheets("Data")
    Set ws = Sheets(2)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With sh
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range("N2:N" & LstRw)
        For Each c In Rng.Cells
            '--------------
            Set FnD = ws.Columns(2).Find(what:=c.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)

            If Not FnD Is Nothing Then
                r = FnD.Row
                With ws
                    .Cells(r, "A").Value = c.Offset(, -1).Value
                    .Cells(r, "B").Value = c.Value
                    .Cells(r, "C").Value = c.Offset(, -3).Value
                End With
            Else:
                With ws
                    r = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

                    .Cells(r, "A").Value = c.Offset(, -1).Value
                    .Cells(r, "B").Value = c.Value
                    .Cells(r, "C").Value = c.Offset(, -3).Value

                End With
            End If
            '----------------------
        Next c

    End With

End Sub
```